# Failed with: success/error was not called, despite both calls being there

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm trying to get my Parse cloud code job to run, but it keeps giving me an error stating `Failed with: success/error was not called`, despite the fact that both calls are at the end of the function. Am I setting it up in a way where they never get called?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("mcItemCount", function(request, response) {

    // Query all users
    var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    // For each user in the DB...       
    return usersQuery.each(function(user) {

        //Query all matchCenterItems associated with them
        var matchCenterItem = Parse.Object.extend("matchCenterItem");
        var mcItemQuery = new Parse.Query(matchCenterItem);
        mcItemQuery.equalTo('parent', user);

        // Set the numberOfItems property equal to the # of matchCenterItems they have
        mcItemQuery.find().then(function(results) {
            var numberOfItems = results.length;
            user.set("numberOfItems", numberOfItems);
        });

    }.then(function() {
        // Set the job's success status
        response.success("mcItemsCount completed successfully.");
        status.success("mcItemsCount completed successfully.");
    }, function(error) {
        // Set the job's error status
        response.error('DAMN IT MAN');
        status.error("mcItemsCount FAAAAIIILLED");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you haven't defined `status`. Replace the `response` parameter in the function definition with `status`, and then drop the `response.success` and `response.error` calls:

```
Parse.Cloud.job("mcItemCount", function(request, status) {
    // Query all users
    var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    // For each user in the DB...       
    return usersQuery.each(function(user) {
        // ...
    }.then(function() {
        // Set the job's success status
        status.success("mcItemsCount completed successfully.");
    }, function(error) {
        // Set the job's error status
        status.error("mcItemsCount FAAAAIIILLED");
    });
});
```